Why formula for operator in another basis is like this?
We have operator $A$ in basis $E$. Transformation matrix from $E$ to $E'$ is $T$. There is a formula for $A$ in new basis $E'$ : $A' = T^{-1}AT$.
We got $Ax = y$, $Tx = x'$, $A'x' = y'$, $T^{-1}y'=y$
$A'x' = y' \Rightarrow T^{-1}ATx'= y' \Rightarrow T^{-1}ATTx = y' \Rightarrow T^{-1}T^{-1}ATTx = y$
Things I don't understand:

why in $A'x' = y' \Rightarrow T^{-1}ATx'= y'$ we apply $T$, if it is trasformation matrix from $E$ to $E'$, to $x'$ if it is already in basis $E'$? Why then we apply $A$ to $(Tx')$ if $A$ is operator in E, but $(Tx')$ is in $E'$?
in detailed formula $T^{-1}T^{-1}ATTx = y$ whats the sense behind $TT$ and $T^{-1}T^{-1}$


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Using your notation with $x=T^{-1}x'$ and $y' = Ty$, shouldn't the $A'$ match $$y' = Ty = TAx = TAT^{-1}x',$$ and so $A' = TAT^{-1}$?

One way to think about this is as follows: Suppose that $T\colon V \to V$ is a linear map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself. If we pick a basis $B= \{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ of $V$, then we may write any vector $v \in V$ uniquely in the form $\sum_{b \in B} c_i.b_i$. The map $v \mapsto (c_i)_{i=1}^n$ thus gives an isomorphism $Q \colon V \to \mathbb R^n$.
On $\mathbb R^n$, the linear map $T$ corresponds to the map given by left-multiplication by a matrix $A$, that is $QT(v) = AQ(v)$ for all $v \in V$. This is just the standard way of associating a matrix to a linear map: $Q$ maps the basis $B$ of $V$ to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$, and so $A(Q(b_i)) = A(e_i)$ is the $i$-th column of $A$, while $QT(b_i)$ gives the coordinates of $T(b_i)$ with respect to $B$.
Now if we are given another basis $B'$ of $V$ then we obtain a new map $Q'\colon V \to \mathbb R^n$, and the matrix of $T$ associated to it is $A'\colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, where $Q'T =A'Q'$. Thus we have the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb R^n @<{Q}<< V @>{Q'}>>\mathbb R^n\\
@V{A}VV @VV{T}V  @VV{A'}V\\
\mathbb R^n @<{Q}<< V @>{Q'}>>\mathbb R^n
\end{CD}$$
It follows that if we want to write $A'$ in terms of $A$, then if we let $P=Q\circ (Q')^{-1}$ we have $A' = PAP^{-1}$ and it is easy to see that $P$ is simply the usual change of basis matrix.

Thanks! my mistake was to think that $Tx = x'$, actually it is opposite $Tx' = x$
